# What is fast path in java

Tags: java

Recently, I'm researching the AbstractQueueSynchronizer.java that contains a method addWaiter. I cannot understand the comment in the addWaiter method,
`"// Try the fast path of enq; backup to full enq on failure"`.

I don't understand the “fast path”. What does the "fast path mean"? I found an explanation at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559463/what-is-meant-by-fast-path-uncontended-synchronization)

Why a specific possible control flow can be more efficient? Who can give me some case?